# Python Calculator Using 2 vars, Operators, and Q (Quit)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple python calculator for an assignment. The basic idea of it is simple and documented all over online, but I am trying to create one where the user actually inputs the operators. So instead of printing 1: addition, 2: subtraction, etc, the user would select + for addition, - for subtraction, etc. I am also trying to make Q or q quit the program. 
Any ideas for how to allow the user to type operators to represent the operation?

Note: I know I still need to define my remainder operation.

```
    import math

loop = 1
choice = 0

while loop == 1:
    print("your options are:")
    print("+ Addition")
    print("- Subtraction")
    print("* Multiplication")
    print("/ Division")
    print("% Remainder")
    print("Q Quit")
    print("***************************")

    choice = str(input("Choose your option: "))
    if choice == +:
        ad1 = float(input("Add this: "))
        ad2 = float(input("to this: "))
        print(ad1, "+", ad2, "=", ad1 + ad2)
    elif choice == -:
        su2 = float(input("Subtract this: "))
        su1 = float(input("from this: "))
        print(su1, "-", su2, "=", su1 - su2)
    elif choice == *:
        mu1 = float(input("Multiply this: "))
        mu2 = float(input("with this: "))
        print(mu1, "*", mu2, "=", mu1 * mu2)
    elif choice == /:
        di1 = float(input("Divide this: "))
        di2 = float(input("by this: "))
        print(di1, "/", di2, "=", di1 / di2)
    elif choice == Q:
        loop = 0

print("Thank-you for using calculator")
```

Comment: just put quotes around the operators: `if choice == '+':`

Comment: It might be clearer to do `while loop:`, and set loop to `True` or `False` instead of `1` or `0`.  (I realize that `True == 1` and `False == 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't need to assign `choice` to zero

Second, you have your code right, but you need to put quotes around the operators in your if statements like this

```
if choice == '+':
```

to show that you are checking for a string

make your loop like this:

```
while 1: #or while True:
    #do stuff

    elif choice == 'Q': #qoutes around Q
           break #use the `break` keyword to end the while loop
```

then, you don't need to assign `loop` at the top of your program

Comment: Many thanks. Second programming assignment for me. Should have remembered I always needed single quotes when referencing the string.

Comment: I did pretty much this exact thing when I started! good luck in the future! :)

Comment: Using break instead of a boolean?  Nice to see that goto is coming back.  :^)

Answer (score 0):

You should try replacing `if choice == +` by `if choice == "+"`.

What you're getting from the input is actually a string, which means it can contain any character, even one that represents an operator.